# WinXP option not showing during boot

Tags: grub2

I have ubuntu 12.10 installed along with Windows xp. Suddenly today when I booted the grub menu is not showing the Windows xp option. The only options shown are to boot in Ubuntu, memtest, Advanced boot. I am sure I did not mess around with any files.

How can I put WinXP back in grub menu?

Comment: Have you tried sudo update-grub from terminal within Ubuntu?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use "boot-repair" from Ubuntu Software-Center and choose recommended repair option. It solves the problems.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Try to update grub.

```
sudo update-grub
```

Comment: @fleamour @mostafa Thanks for the answers. I didnt try`sudo update-grub` I used boot repair and it solved.